# Insert Body field in Insert Email Link Dialog in Sitecore Link field

Tags: sitecore-client

In the Sitecore link field, click on `Insert email`, a dialog box opens (attached in the below images).
It has fields like

- Displayed Text
- Subject
- E-mail Address
- Style

[image]

In the above dialog box, I am trying to add one more field **Body**, but it is not appearing.

I tried to make changes in the file `Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\MailLink\MailLink.xml`
and customized `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.MailLink\MailLinkForm`
class. But nothing happened.

Can someone guide me that these are the right files I am making changes in or I need to do something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog which is appearing is the one from the SPEAK UI. In order to add your new text field, you will need to add a textbox to the presentation details of the dialog.

**Note that, it will need to use [Sitecore Rocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakobChristensen.SitecoreRocks) to update the UI for SPEAK because you will need to have access to the renderings.**

Navigate to the Core database and then to the path `/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertEmailDialog`.

Right click on the InsertEmailDialog > Tasks > Design Layout, you can add the rendering for the TextBox.

[image]

Once the textbox added, you can update the code.

The JS is found at `/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertEmailDialog.js` and the backend code is at the namespace `Sitecore.Speak.Applications.InsertEmail, Sitecore.Speak.Applications`

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind support. I am able to add new fields in that dialog. But I am still facing few issues like:                                                              
 1- how to add new placeholders for newly added renderings.(Currently I am using existing placeholders of existing fields like EmailLabelCol.Content and EmailTextCol.Content  but this is distorting UI)  2- How to call my customized  class in place of Sitecore.Speak.Applications.InsertEmail.           Can you please guide me how to fix this?